# Show vectors are a basis and find coordinate vector to this basis.

Tags: vector-spaces

I got 4 vectors

$u1=(2,3,0,5)$

$U2=(1,-2,1,0)$

$u3=(1,0,-1,2)$

$U4=(-3,-1,1,1)$

and i have to show they form the basis of $R^4$.

Is it right i simply test if they are linearly independent and if they are, I've shown that they are a basis to R?
Or do i need to prove that they span R as well? If that is the case how do show that they span all of R?

[image]

is this right?

When i do that i get a full rank with x=0,y=0,z=0 and k=0 and therefore I've proven they are linearly independent and therefore form basis.

So far so good.

I also have to find the coordinate vector to U5 in relation basis and here i have gaussed them all but instead of last row being 0's I've put vector u5 coordinates here. i have gaussed it down and find that the coordinate vector for vector u5 in relation to basis is (0,-3,4,0) - is this correct?
[enter image description here][3]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $B\subseteq V$. Then the following statements are equivalent

1. $B$ is a basis of $V$
2. $B$ spans $V$ and $B$ is linearly independent
3. $B$ contains at least $\dim V$-many linearly independent vectors
4. $B$ spans $V$ and contains at most $\dim V$-many vectors.

In your case $V=\mathbb R^4$, $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\}$. Since $\dim\mathbb R^4=4$ and $B$ contains exactly 4 vectors, the only thing you have to do is to check whether these vectors are linearly independent. You have done this correctly with the Gauß-algorithm.

Since we now know that $B$ is a basis, every vector of $\mathbb R^4$ can be represented as a linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$. In particular, $u_5$ can. Again, you have found the coordinates with the Gauß-algorithm correctly. To check if the coordinates are correct, just form the corresponding linear combination and see if it simplifies to $u_5$.

Answer (score 0):

Your vectors belong to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ so it is $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ that is the vector space that has the basis consisting of your given vectors and not $\mathbb{R}$. Now for your vectors to be a basis they need to be both a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and also linearly independent. So you would usually have to show both of these conditions are satisfied separately. However if you already know that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ is 4, and you have 4 vectors so...(do you really need to check both conditions)

Comment: So i just need to check whether they are lineary independent? And thats it.